# Read Gmail emails using Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, gmail

We want to automate actions based on emails we receive by email from different management systems from devices in our network

I have tried this small script, but it lists only the subject, not the body

```
# load rss-feed
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient

# access the rss-feed
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential ("scominbox@domain", "Password")

# download the rss as xml
[xml]$xml= $webclient.DownloadString("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom")

# display only sender name and message title as custom table
$format= @{Expression={$_.title};Label="Title"},@{Expression={$_.author.name};Label="Author"}

# display the table
$xml.feed.entry | format-table $format
```

How can I read the emails?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/1181265/read-gmail-emails-using-powershell)

Comment: It's not always easy to know in which site we should post our questions, so you must accept that we sometimes do that to get our answers

Comment: There are better mechanisms to get useful and quality answers : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/282031

Comment: you might want to try going though the gmail api.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) one could define `format` with the value `full` or `raw`:

> Optional query parameters format  string  The format to return the
>   message in.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> ```
> "full": Returns the full email message data with body content parsed in the 
> payload field; the raw field is not used. (default)
> "raw": Returns the full email message data with body content in the raw field 
> as a base64url encoded string; the payload field is not used.
> ```

Comment: Thx for trying but it looks like that is for the API, not the RSS feed I'm requesting towards

Comment: Oh ok. Then [this](http://superuser.com/a/1181273/313985) post could help.

Answer (score 1):

Please change code under  `#display` only sender name and message title as custom table

to:

```
$format= @{Expression={$_.title};Label="Title"},
         @{Expression={$_.author.name};Label="Author"}, 
         @{Expression={$_.summary};Label="Body"}
```

In XML file email body is saved under summary tag.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use:**

```
$xml.feed.entry | Select *
```

It will return the data in the following format:

```
title           : 
summary         : Test body
link            : link
modified        : <date>
issued          : <date>
id              : <date>
author          : author
Name            : entry
LocalName       : entry
NamespaceURI    : http://purl.org/atom/ns#
Prefix          : 
NodeType        : Element
ParentNode      : feed
OwnerDocument   : #document
IsEmpty         : False
Attributes      : {}
HasAttributes   : False
SchemaInfo      : System.Xml.XmlName
InnerXml        : <OMITTED>
InnerText       : <OMITTED>
NextSibling     : 
PreviousSibling : modified
Value           : 
ChildNodes      : {title, summary, link, modified...}
FirstChild      : title
LastChild       : author
HasChildNodes   : True
IsReadOnly      : False
OuterXml        : <OMITTED>
BaseURI         : 
PreviousText    :
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please provide a more specific example about how to access the body of the mail.